# Cannot red property of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have this in my html view.

```
<form name="adduser" id="signupForm" novalidate>
    <span>First Name</span>
    <label class="item item-input" id="profileLabel">
    <input id="profileInput" type="text"
                     ng-model="user.fname"
                     class="form-control"                              
                     placeholder="{{fnamePlaceholder}}"
                     ng-minlength="1" >
    </label>

    <div id="name-group" class="form-group-lg">
         <button type="submit" ng-click="updateData(user)" id="initiateSignUp" class=" button button-positive  button-block" >
         Save and continue
         </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

and this is the start of my controller

```
$scope.updateData=function(user){
    console.log (user.fname)
}
```

but i keep getting

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'fname' of undefined

Comment: What's your `$scope`? If $scope is a user, then would it not just be ng-model="fname". The problem is user is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

First, define `$scope.user = {};` in your controller.

You don't have to pass `user` as a parameter to your `ngClick` callback. The `user` variable is defined on the scope, so there's no reason to pass it as parameter.

Simply use `$scope.user` in your callback.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a property on an object that is `undefined`

in the begin you need to initialize the user.

```
$scope.user = {};
```

Answer (score 0):

While Angular can create primitive values on your controller for you automatically, it can't create complex types likes objects or arrays. You need to initialize these yourself in the controller before trying to use them in bindings

Answer (score 0):

Try predefining user as an object.

```
$scope.user = {};

$scope.updateData = function(user) {
  console.log (user.fname);
};
```

Since user is an object and not defined before using it, complier wont able create a property for user.